# Using transition effect instead of easing

Tags: slideshow, transition, easing

I am trying to have my slides in a specific transition. Right now, I have something called "easing" which is used within my slideshow. The problem is that I have no idea how to change that specific portion. I have modified the slideshow to a great extent to make it usable for the work project I am working on. I definitely wanna use that for work and for myself, because I find it to be such a good slideshow. But, I would love to have a simple transition like the Sudo Slider, as opposed to easing.

(once I have a basic transitition, I could change it to another sudo transitiion effect, so that will not be a problem)
Anyhow, the plugin I found - the Sudo Slider - is found on this website
http://webbies.dk/assets/files/SudoSlider/package/demos/continuous.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
   $(document).ready(function(){
      var sudoSlider = $("#slider").sudoSlider({
         numeric: true
         continuous:true
      });
   });
</script>
```

As for the slideshow (called MovingBoxes), this is one of things I have modified within the code. As for the speed, I have to put it at 1 to "remove" the effect of the easing. But I would really like to be capable of using the Sudo Slider transition effects instead (or any other non-easing transition effect). How could I achieve this?

```
$.movingBoxes.defaultOptions = {
        // Appearance
        startPanel   : 1,
        reducedSize  : 1, 
        fixedHeight  : false, 

        // Behaviour
        initAnimation: false,
        stopAnimation: false, 
        hashTags: true, 
        wrap: true, 
        buildNav: false,     
        navFormatter: null, 
        easing: 'easeInOutQuint',

        // Times
        speed: 1, // animation time in milliseconds - 500 is original
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think that transition effects are just setting an option, it't not.

Each of the transition effects you see in e.g. SudoSlider are made of complex code.

You could take a look at the function "boxTemplate" in: http://webbies.dk/assets/files/SudoSlider/package/js/jquery.sudoSlider.js

The "boxTemplate" function defines the different effects involving boxes in SudoSlider.

If that could easily be moved to work with a script like MovingBoxes, I would happily do it.

But making it work with MovingBoxes would involve rewriting most of it, something that's not going to happen here on StackOverflow.

Comment: I wouldn't mind rewriting it myself, if I knew how. The problem is that I wouldn't know where to start nor how to start. If you would know of any resources or any websites capable of teaching me the knowhow, I would gladly rewrite the code.

Comment: You would need to learn a great deal of JavaScript/jQuery. 
You need to learn enough so that you could write it yourself. 
You can start here: http://try.jquery.com/

Comment: Thanks webbies! I shall look at that.